# [vba]Viewsingle Filter property returns runtime error

Tags: vba, ms-project, object-model

I have been writing a fairly complex routine for MS Project.  Long story short, whenever I try to access the filter property on a viewsingle object I receive a Run-time error '1101' (the argument is not valid). I can access every other property (whether it is present or not) both in immediate and in code.

The actual code is along lines of

---

If vS.Filter <> "" Then  'have a filter
    ..do stuff
End if

---

The object model states that the .Filter property is Set/Get (and .Filter name is a string).

So, I am very confused - if anyone has come across this knows the answer it would be appreciated.

//Adding in the code fragment.  I have fixed this for filters however, the same fix doesn't work for tables IF (and I suppose this could be the same for filters) the View has suffered some corruption and is missing a Table (or filter?) Object.  I think that I will need to add an error checker for the runtime error - in this instance as can't seem to actually test for non-existence of a Get/Set Object property.

---

Dim v As View, vS As ViewSingle, vC As ViewCombination, pctDone As Single, lcount As Long
Dim f As Filter, t As Table

For Each v In ThisProject.Views

```
lcount = lcount + 1

If v.Single Then   'Process Single views first

        Set vS = ThisProject.ViewsSingle.Item(v.Name)

        'Check for Resource type
        Select Case True
            Case v.Type = pjResourceItem

                'check filter
                Set f = vS.Filter
                If f.Name <> "" Then  'have a filter
                    For lnglist = 1 To ColRFExPreview.Count

                        If f.Name = ColRFExPreview.Item(lnglist) Then
                            lngLbInd = lnglist - 1
                            f.Name = VTI_FRM.LB_ResFltrs.List(lngLbInd)
                            vS.Filter = f
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                'check table (we will always check the table)
                Set t = vS.Table
                For lnglist = 1 To ColRTExPreview.Count

                    If t.Name = ColRTExPreview.Item(lnglist) Then
                        lngLbInd = lnglist - 1
                        t.Name = VTI_FRM.LB_ResTbles.List(lngLbInd)
                        vS.Table = t
                    End If
                Next

            Case Else   'Not a resource type

                'check filter
                Set f = vS.Filter
                If f.Name <> "" Then  'have a filter
                    For lnglist = 1 To ColTFExPreview.Count
                        If f.Name = ColTFExPreview.Item(lnglist) Then
                            lngLbInd = lnglist - 1
                            f.Name = VTI_FRM.LB_FILTERS.List(lngLbInd)
                            vS.Filter = f
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                'check table (we will always check the table)
                Set t = vS.Table
                For lnglist = 1 To ColTTExPreview.Count
                    If t.Name = ColTTExPreview.Item(lnglist) Then
                        lngLbInd = lnglist - 1
                        t.Name = VTI_FRM.LB_TABLES.List(lngLbInd)
                        vS.Table = t
                    End If
                Next

            End Select

        Else    'Combination View - just need to check that Bottomview and topview need to change

            Set vC = ThisProject.ViewsCombination(v.Name)

            For lnglist = 1 To ColViewExPreview.Count

                If vC.BottomView.Name = ColViewExPreview.Item(lnglist) Then
                    lngLbInd = lnglist - 1
                    vC.BottomView.Name = VTI_FRM.LB_Views.List(lngLbInd)
                End If

                If vC.TopView.Name = ColViewExPreview.Item(lnglist) Then
                    lngLbInd = lnglist - 1
                    vC.TopView.Name = VTI_FRM.LB_Views.List(lngLbInd)
                End If

            Next


    End If
```

---

Comment: Think I may have worked this out, the Properties '.Filter' and '.Table' Get/Set objects therefore need to assign (e.g.) vs.filter to a 'Filter' variable (e.g. Dim f as Filter, set f = vs.filter, then test f.Name) - this works for filters definitely, tables slightly more complex as both TaskTables and ResourceTables.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please post the actual code you are using in your question, as much as is reasonable for other members to try and recreate the issue themselves and solve it.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? It appears that you are changing the *name* of the underlying view objects (filters and tables), but are you trying to change the *object* instead? In other words, are you looking to rename a table from something like "Entry" to something like "My entry"? Or do you want to modify the view to use a different table? If so, look at [ViewEditSingle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.vieweditsingle).

Comment: Also look at the [Organizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.organizer) which is typically used to reset views, etc. by replacing the objects in the current file with a clean version from another file.

Comment: What I've done is create a means to quickly port my own collection of views, tables and filters  into different environments by changing the Prefixes on Views, Tables and Filters (VTF) in a bulk type update.  This cannot be done quickly using organizer if one has a lot of custom VTF.  Certain ViewSingle Objects do not have a table, querying such objects for a table generates runtime error.t I wanted to know if there was a way that I hadn't thought of to identify those items without resulting to error handing to identify a _natural_ state (e.g. something like the Java 'undefined' property).

Comment: The Organizer methods: [OrganizerMoveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.organizermoveitem), [OrganizerDeleteItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.organizerdeleteitem), and [OrganizerRenameItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.organizerrenameitem) work well and quickly, but perhaps your method will be fine with a bit of error handling. As you may have discovered by now, the Project API is not as complete as one would hope.

Comment: You're right, of course, but I wanted to explore the Object Model in more detail.  As you say the API is not as complete as one might wish.  However, it's good to know its limitations.  Thanks for your help.